# Can I open a command prompt with admin privleges in Vista WITHOUT my mouse?

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm accustomed to opening a shell in Windows with the keyboard, but when I want admin privileges, the only way I know is to right click on the start menu icon.

There must be a keyboard-only way, right?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Option 1 - requires that you use the Vista-style Start Menu*

- Hit <kbd>Windows</kbd> key
- Type `cmd`
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Done!

*Option 2 - works with Classic Start Menu, requires Quick Launch to be enabled*

- Create a shortcut to cmd.exe on your Quick Launch bar
- Right-click the shortcut, select Properties, Advanced, and check the "Run as administrator" box
- Quick Launch icons can be launched using <kbd>Windows</kbd> key + NUMBER, where NUMBER is the position of the icon, so if your new cmd shortcut is the 1st icon, use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
- Done!

Comment: For which versions of windows are these options working ? Would be nice to precise. Typically, the first one requires Vista, it's written, but second for example doesn't work for XP. Does it work on Vista, or only Windows 7 ?

Comment: XP doesn't apply since you don't need to run as administrator, and the solution will work in Vista and up?

Comment: In a properly configuerd XP environment you do often need to runas admin.

Comment: TBH, I don't think the question is relevant to XP. My answer applies to Vista and 7.

Answer (score 15):

Do this:

1. Press <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the run prompt
2. Type runas /user:ADMINUSERNAME cmd.exe

Answer (score 1):

i'm using [ColorConsole](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/ColorConsole) instead of the windows command prompt (the reason being not so much the variety of colour schemes but the favorite commands, copy/paste, tabbed interface and HTML export. you're probably asking this question to save time, so CC will save you even more). i have set CC to run always as admin from the advanced shortcut properties menu, of course you can do that with CMD.EXE too. just create a new shortcut for cmd.exe, make it to run always as admin and assign a hotkey to this shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way:

1. Press <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the run dialog
2. Type `cmd` into the text field 
    (only the first time, will be saved afterwards, use cmd.exe if cmd gives you problems)
3. Press <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> 
    (Crtl+Shift+Enter or +OK runs the command as admin)

[image]

Depending on your settings you might need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to acknowledge UCA promt.

This only works if your user has admin rights, if not I would recommend EBGreen's answer (runas /user:administrator cmd.exe).

Answer (score 0):

already discussed good options (possibly better than mine) however I personally press start / Windows flag button on my keyboard and type cmd, then press the context menu button (between right windows flag and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  then press down and <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10:

**Method 1**

- Hit <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Type `cmd` in the textbox
- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

**Method 2**

- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- Type `cmd` in the textbox
- Hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>+</kbd> in Numpad
- Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

**Method 3**

- Hit <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- Type `cmd`
- Hit <kbd>RIGHT ARROW</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

**Method 4** (If you have Replace Command Prompt with Powershell in Win+X menu setting enabled)

- Hit <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
- Use <kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd> key to navigate to `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Some ways can work with earlier versions to (Especially 1).

Answer (score -1):

You can launch Command Prompt with admin privileges without using a mouse. First, you need to open a Run box by pressing Windows + R keys. Type “cmd” into the box and then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to run the command as an administrator.

Comment: I think that's what the accepted answer said -- eleven years ago. :)

If you are still using Vista in 2020, I'm sorry to hear that.